# When a radio button is checked on the Google Docs sidebar, how can I trigger an action in a Google Doc?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Doc with some text and I have created a Sidebar. What I want is that when someone highlights a word, then click on an option using a radio button in the sidebar, the word will highlight in a colour depending on the option selected.
I've already got the sidebar with the radio buttons, using HtmlService, and I've got some Google Apps Script which will highlight the word.
What I'm struggling with is to find a way to register which radio button has been clicked which can then be used to decide which colour to select.
I've managed to trigger actions using Javascript in the HTML code but I can't link it with the function that highlights the word. I've been trying to set a variable when the button is selected which could then be used in an If statement to decide what colour to add.
Here's the GAS code and HTML that I've written so far.
If anyone's got any ideas as to what's missing, they would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

```
  //Function to create sidebar and get HTML from file called Index
function sidebar() {

      var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
          .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
          .setTitle('Writing codes');

      DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput);  

    }
```

Below is the file "Index.html"

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <base target="_top">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Highlight an area and click on a code below to highlight it in the text.</p>

   <form>
   <input type="radio" name="error" id="GrammarBut"/> Grammar<br />
   <input type="radio" name="error" id="VocabBut"/> Vocabulary<br />
   <input type="radio" name="error" id="WOBut"/> Word order<br />
   <br />
<div class="block">
    <button class="blue">Add</button>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the function highlightText which highlights the word if selected.

```
function highlightText() {
  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if (selection) {
  var elements = selection.getRangeElements();
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var element2 = elements[i];

// Only modify elements that can be edited as text; skip images and other non-text elements.
   if (element2.getElement().editAsText) {
   var text = element2.getElement().editAsText();
   if (element2.isPartial()) {
       text.setBackgroundColor(element2.getStartOffset(), element2.getEndOffsetInclusive(), "#FFFD4C");
       } else {
       text.setBackgroundColor("#FFFD4C");       
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an onclick event that triggers a client side JavaScript function with a reference to the triggered element. Then call the server side function with your color choice.

Radio button element:

```
<form>
   <input onclick="chngColor(this)" type="radio" name="error" id="GrammarBut"/> Grammar<br />
   <input onclick="chngColor(this)" type="radio" name="error" id="VocabBut"/> Vocabulary<br />
   <input onclick="chngColor(this)" type="radio" name="error" id="WOBut"/> Word order<br />
   <br />
```

Client side JavaScript:

```
function chngColor(element)
{
  var id = element.id;
  var color;

  if(id == "GrammerBut")
    color = "the color you need";
  else if(id == "VocabBut")
    color = "next color";
  else if(id == "WOBut")
    color = "final color";

  google.script.run.highlightText(color);
}
```

Then just change the server side function to take in a parameter to set the color, or whatever else you need to do.

Comment: Gerneio that works brilliantly! Thank you so much! For anyone else reading this with a similar problem, in the HTML document I put the button HTML as above and also the chngColor function between <script> tags. Then in the GAS part I have the highlightText function.